# Trouble with printing positive integers in java

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I am practicing and i need help with this code . I need to read integers from the keyboard and print how many are positive Any help in what im doing wrong in my code below?

```
    int size = 10;
    int count = 0;
    int cuenta = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[size];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 digits: ");
    while (count < size) {
        numbers[count] = keyboard.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] >= 0) {
            cuenta++;

            System.out.println("There are " + cuenta);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: It always help if you say what you're expecting to happen, and what actually happens. Does nothing happen? Does it print the wrong thing? Do you get an exception - if so, please give the stacktrace for the exception

Comment: Put `println()` outside your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to print out the count after `for` `loop` so that it has right answer

```
System.out.println("There are " + cuenta);
```

Comment: yeah i just noticed it haha thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 1):

You have your logic to check for positive integers right.  To point you in the right direction think about your print statement and whether it need to be within the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] >= 0) {
            cuenta++;

            System.out.println("There are " + cuenta);
        }

    }
```